# Check overlapping points (multiple files)

Tags: qgis, python

I am trying to write a Python script to run through multiple point shapefiles to check if there are any overlapping points between them. I wish to not output any files if there are no overlapping points & output as a CSV file with Lat/Long attribute?

```
import processing
import os
import shutil
import csv
import re

filelist=[]

path = 'FOLDER_PATH'
files = os.listdir(path)

# loop through folder for .shp file
for f in files:
    if (f.endswith(".shp")):
        filepath=(os.path.join(path,f))
        filelist.append(filepath)
        
# loop-1
for i in range(len(filelist)):
    filename1=(re.split(r'[.|\\]',filelist[i])[2])

# loop-2
    for x in range(len(filelist)):
        if (filelist[i] != filelist[x]):
            filename2=(re.split(r'[.|\\]',filelist[x])[2])

# Process loop-1 as 'INPUT' and loop-2 as 'INTERSECT' with the "Extract by location" processing toolbox.
            processing.run("qgis:extractbylocation",\
            {'INPUT':filelist[i],'PREDICATE':[0,5],'INTERSECT':filelist[x],'OUTPUT':path+r'\\'+filename1+filename2+r'.shp'})
```

Comment: Hello. With regards to the desired result you clearly describe in your question, it would make it easier to help you if you also clarify what your current script does, and where you are stuck with your current attempts

Comment: Added some comments. Hope that is clearer. Thanks

Comment: A few additional questions: does your current script return anything or throw some errors? You wrote you expect a CSV, but you seem to output some shp? Overall do you want to return multiple files or just one with the intersection points ?

Comment: It will output the shp file, even if there is no overlapping points found. I want it to only output/save files out when there is overlapping features.

Comment: I did not know the processing toolbox enough to provide you with an answer. What if you first output to temporary layer (instead of file currently), then check somehow if the layer is not empty, then only export that layer to shapefile ?

Comment: In what way? For example shape1 compared to all others? then shape 2 compared to all others?

Comment: The processing toolbox can output a temporary layer if the OUTPUT parameter is set to 'memory'. Then you can check the feature count of that layer and export only if needed.

Comment: Must I load the TEMPORARY_OUTPUT into the layer panel to use it? How to I access the TEMPORARY_OUTPUT ?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this in a completely different way. This answer does not attempt to fix your current code, but it does produce the result you are aiming for.

```py
import os

filelist=[]

path = r"FOLDER_PATH"
files = os.listdir(path)
  
for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".shp"):
        filepath=(os.path.join(path,f))
        filelist.append(filepath)

# merge all points together into one layer
merged = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':filelist,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

# calculate a unique id field (this output is saved to disk because virtual layer struggles with in-memory inputs)
merged = processing.run("native:fieldcalculator", {'INPUT':merged,'FIELD_NAME':'uid','FIELD_TYPE':1,'FIELD_LENGTH':0,'FIELD_PRECISION':0,'FORMULA':'$id','OUTPUT':os.path.join(path, 'merged.shp')})['OUTPUT']

# make a virtual layer of only intersecting points
intersecting_points = processing.run("qgis:executesql", {'INPUT_DATASOURCES':[merged],'INPUT_QUERY':'SELECT *\nFROM input1 AS a, input1 AS b\nWHERE ST_Equals(a.geometry, b.geometry) AND a.uid <> b.uid','INPUT_UID_FIELD':'id','INPUT_GEOMETRY_FIELD':'','INPUT_GEOMETRY_TYPE':2,'INPUT_GEOMETRY_CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

# add longitude and latitude as fields
xy = processing.run("native:addxyfields", {'INPUT':intersecting_points,'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

# write CSV header (field names)
csv_path = os.path.join(path, 'out_csv.csv')
with open(csv_path, 'w+') as file:
    file.write(', '.join([str(field) for field in xy.fields().names()]) + '\n')

# append results to CSV
with open(csv_path, 'a') as file:
    for f in xy.getFeatures():
        file.write(', '.join([str(attribute) for attribute in f.attributes()]) + '\n')
```

###### Result

(Using a simplified dataset)

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Why do we merged the features?

Comment: So there is only one layer to deal with. The SQL query finds all intersections in one operation, without the need to loop through all the files twice and extracting the intersecting features that many times. The added benefit of using merge is that it adds the filepath of the source layers as attributes, so you know which files have the intersections.

Comment: The process seen to take longer than expected and the results are not correct.

Comment: You will have to be more specific about what is not correct if you want me to improve my answer. How many point features are you using? For a test on 1820 (total) points, this ran in a few seconds and generated a result just like the CSV I show in my answer. Do your layers have a spatial index? If not, creating one will likely much improve performance.

Comment: I have 326 overlapping point features but only 13 features are output into the csv
shpfile - https://we.tl/t-RA4Aitf28z

Comment: There appears to be an issue with your points: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjvcP.jpg

Comment: Could you elaborate? Please note that the points are randomly placed. I'm just using it to test with python.